# JavaScript equivalent to JQuery .next()

Tags: javascript, siblings

Is there a JavaScript method similar to jQuery .next()? I want to find the next element that has the class of "error" relative to the element. I've tried using `.nextSibling` as a loop but couldn't figure it out. Didn't know if there was an easier way to go about it without jQuery.

For instance, if I have this code:

```
<div id="section">
    <div id="test">test</div>
    <span class="info">Information</span>
    <span class="error">Error!</span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the next `.error` class closest to `#test`, if I have a `#section2` and a `#test2` I would want to get the `.error` class closest to `#test2` and so on.

Comment: I suspect you might misunderstand what `.next(selector)` does. It doesn't search through siblings to match the selector. It just filters, either collecting the very next sibling if it matches or nothing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `nextElementSibling` property returns the element immediately following the specified element, in the same tree level.

Example: Get the HTML content of the next sibling of a list item:

```
var x = document.getElementById("item1").nextElementSibling
```

The `nextElementSibling` property might help.

Comment: The `nextElementSibling` just return `next sibling` element not `next` element. For example, if we have hierarchical elements it just returns the next element of our element in the parent block

Answer (score 3):

Best bet would be to search through the jQuery code and see what they did.
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js

At a glance, I do see some calls to "nextSibling" and "previousSibling."

Also see here:
[How to get next element using JavaScript-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289932/how-to-get-next-element-using-javascript-only)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is the pure javascript for you:

HTML

```
<div id="nodes">
    <div class="error">This is error Node</div>  
    <div class="nextElement">This is next Element</div>
</div>
```

Javscript:

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.getElementById('nodes').children ),
    errorNode = document.getElementsByClassName('error')[0];
var indexOfError = nodes.indexOf(errorNode);
var nextElement = nodes[indexOfError + 1];
alert(nextElement.innerText);
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/cHJjg/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be looking for `document.getElementsByClassName()`... if the elements with class=error are not direct siblings in the DOM, then there's not a good way to find them otherwise.  It's elementary, but you can just search through the array returned by `document.getElementsByClassName('error')` until you find your starting element, and then you know the next item in the array will be the next element in the DOM.

See also [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).  Won't work in old IE, but works for all modern browsers.